# merge 2 array of hashes based on different keys in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have 2 query results one of them is an array of hashes like this

`[{"user_id"=>"1", "latlng"=>[#<BigDecimal:7fc67f8412d0,'0.43653226E2',18(36)>, #<BigDecimal:7fc67f840560,'-0.793831843E2',18(36)>], "loc"=>["Toronto", "Ontario", "Canada"]}, {"user_id"=>"2", "latlng"=>[#<BigDecimal:7fc67f84a8f8,'0.43653226E2',18(36)>, #<BigDecimal:7fc67f849d18,'-0.793831843E2',18(36)>], "loc"=>["Toronto", "Ontario", "Canada"]}, {"user_id"=>"3", "latlng"=>[#<BigDecimal:7fc67f848828,'0.43653226E2',18(36)>, #<BigDecimal:7fc67f848210,'-0.793831843E2',18(36)>], "loc"=>["Toronto", "Ontario", "Canada"]}, {"user_id"=>"4", "latlng"=>[#<BigDecimal:7fc67f852620,'0.43653226E2',18(36)>, #<BigDecimal:7fc67f851b30,'-0.793831843E2',18(36)>], "loc"=>["Toronto", "Ontario", "Canada"]}, {"user_id"=>"5", "latlng"=>[#<BigDecimal:7fc67f85ae88,'0.43653226E2',18(36)>, #<BigDecimal:7fc67f85a9b0,'-0.793831843E2',18(36)>], "loc"=>["Toronto", "Ontario", "Canada"]}]`

the second is an active record relations object of users,

`<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 4, email: "hello.misc@gmail.com", username: "steve", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 13, current_sign_in_at: "2017-02-18 21:16:17", last_sign_in_at: "2017-01-14 20:32:57", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",  confirmed_at: "2016-12-13 01:42:57", confirmation_sent_at: "2016-12-13 01:42:55", unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: "2016-12-13 01:42:55", updated_at: "2017-02-18 22:03:46", slug: "user2", uuid: "xdn5n5z3fmr4", impressions_count: 1, likers_count: 3, lat: #<BigDecimal:7fc67fc39130,'0.0',9(27)>, lng: #<BigDecimal:7fc67fc38c30,'0.0',9(27)>, currently_online: false, status: "unverified", deleted_at: nil>, #<User id: 5, email: "jack@gmail.com", username: "user21", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2017-02-17 02:49:07", last_sign_in_at: "2017-02-17 02:49:07", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",  confirmed_at: "2017-02-17 02:49:10", confirmation_sent_at: "2017-02-17 02:49:07", unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: "2017-02-17 02:49:07", updated_at: "2017-02-17 02:49:43", slug: "user21", uuid: "xtffdh2ajnp7", impressions_count: 1, likers_count: 0, lat: #<BigDecimal:7fc67fca6758,'0.0',9(27)>, lng: #<BigDecimal:7fc67fca5ec0,'0.0',9(27)>, currently_online: false, status: "unverified", deleted_at: nil>]>`

What I want to do, is to merge the first array of hashes into the activerecord relations based on the foreign key of the first array,

so if the first array has an user_id of 3, i want to insert that hash into that active record of the user with an ID of 3 on the active record object.

I came up up with this

`index =  a1.group_by{|entry| entry["id"]}
    i2= a2.map{|entry| (index[entry.id] || []).reduce(entry, :merge) }`

but its not merging them together at all.. what am I doing wrong?

edit: Not all of the first array is relevent, I only want to selectively get the item from the first array based on whats returned in the active record collection of the second query

edit2: I am not looking to save the data back, I just want to merge the data set to display it back in a view template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can do something like this:

```
# users is an array of ActiveRecord::Relation
# extra_data is the hash
users.each do |user|
  # .detect basically will return an object (first appearance) or nil
  data = extra_data.detect{|d| d["user_id"].to_i == user.id}
  if data.present?
    user.lat = data["latlng"][0]
    user.lng = data["latlng"][1]
    # if you want to attach "loc", add a attr_accesor :loc in your Use model
    # user.loc = data["loc"]
  end
end
```

If you want to know more about `detect` method, [read the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect).

Comment: thanks! I used this and @mysmallidea's reply to make it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Array#map` or `collect` on the collection, you're going to end up with an array instead of an ActiveRecord collection, which may not be what you want.

You could add virtual attributes to the User model and then iterate over the collection:

```
# app/models/user.rb
attr_accessor :latlon, :loc

users.each do |user|
  if location = location_array[user.id.to_s]
    user.latlon = location['latlng']
    user.loc = location['loc']
  end
end
```

This probably won't be very efficient, but for a small paginated dataset it might not be a big deal.

Another option would be to use a [decorator pattern](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-decorators/), which acts like a wrapper around your user object. In this case you would add your location attributes to the decorator rather than injecting them into the collection. Have a look at the [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) gem for a good overview.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! But I am not saving it back the db, I just need the collection to display back to the user, so it doesnt really matter if its an active record collection

Comment: In any case, the solution presented above would not save it to the db - it just adds an accessible attribute into each item in the user collection.

Comment: Did you try this solution? As I said it does not save it back to the db, it just adds it as a virtual attribute on each object in the collection. If this isn't what you're looking for, please clarify your question.

Comment: hey, thanks for that suggestion, the decorator is actually quite a nice suggestion, it made me learn how it works and its use cases! Thanks for that. I didnt end up using a new gem just for this one use case, I added the virtual attribute like you suggested, and using a combination of your reply and @rogelio 's reply. I got it working! Thank you!!